# react js: passing variable in 2nd render using useEffect not working

Tags: reactjs

```
const [show, setTracker] = useState(false);

 const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date());
 const changeDate = (e) => {
   setDateState(e);
 };
 console.log(dateState);
 var date = moment(dateState).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
 //localStorage.setItem("pikerdate", pikerdate);
 function clickTracker(e) {
   setTracker(!show);
 }






useEffect(() => {
   const config = {
     headers: {
       Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
     },
   };
   //remove this date after setting up the admin pannel

   axios
     .get(
       "https:url=" +
         date,
       config

       // config
     )
     .then((res) => {
       console.log(res.data.Diet);

       let obj = res.data.Diet.find((o) => o.mealName === "lunch");
       let breakfast = res.data.Diet.find((o) => o.mealName === "breakfast");
       let earlymorning1 = res.data.Diet.find(
         (o) => o.mealName === "early morning"
       );
       let dinner = res.data.Diet.find((o) => o.mealName === "dinner");
       let afternoonsnack = res.data.Diet.find(
         (o) => o.mealName === "afternoon snack"
       );
       let middaysnack = res.data.Diet.find(
         (o) => o.mealName === "mid day snack"
       );
       let dinnerdrink = res.data.Diet.find(
         (o) => o.mealName === "dinner drink"
       );

       // if (earlymorning=)
       // {

       // }
       // console.log(obj);
       //setdata(obj);
       // setbreakType(res.data.Diet[5].food);
       // setbreakfast(res.data.Diet.food);
       // setbreakfastTime(res.data.Diet.time);

       // setdetails(res.data.details);
       setearlymoring(earlymorning1);
       setDinner(dinner);
       setafternoon(afternoonsnack);
       setmidday(middaysnack);
       setdinnerdrink(dinnerdrink);
       //  setlunch(res.data.Diet[6].food);
       setbreakfast(breakfast);
       setlunch(obj);
       // setlunchtime(res.data.Diet[6].time);
     });
 }, [date]);

 return (
   <>
     {console.log(date)}
     {show ? <TrackerByDate dataFromParent={date} /> : null}
     <div style={{ width: "260px" }} className="res-calendar">
       <Calendar
         className={["c1", "c2"]}
         onChange={changeDate}
         onClickDay={clickTracker}
         value={dateState}
       />
     </div>
```

i am tring to pass  A DATE to the child component every time i click on the callander date but the first vallue is only passed (todays date ) to the child component  `<TrackerByDate dataFromParent={date} />`

'{console.log(date)}' is printing the date correctly but when i pass it to child i recive as todays date

how to pass any date throgh this

Answer (score 0):

Your date might need to be an observable value. Is trackerbydate a React.PureComponent or wrapped in a memo()? Bet this is not the issue but how are you logging date in the child component? Are you using react-Dom to inspect the component tree state?

Alternatively see if you get an updated value by logging props.dataFromParent in the Trackerbydate component scope.

The other issue might be that date is now a global scope variable. Using var binds date to the global scope so switching out for const or let is recommended. For this case const would work since values are not mutated and are computed from the dateState..

FYI referencing global scope values in react is antipattern. If you attempt to access global scope date it will not rerender it. Anything passed via props however will be accessible via this.props (components) or just props (first argument) of a functional. These values are observable and will trigger component rerenders.

Updated with examples

See TrackerByDate and the `const` rename. Also curious if the prop `dataFromParent` is meant to be called `dateFromParent`.

```js
const TrackerByDate = (props) => {
  // perhaps dataFromParent should be renamed to dateFromParent?
  console.log(props.dataFromParent, "date logged in child")

 return <div>{props.dataFromParent}</div>
}

const ParentComponent = () => {

 const [show, setTracker] = useState(false);

 const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date());
 const changeDate = (e) => {
   setDateState(e);
 };
 console.log(dateState);
 const date = moment(dateState).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
 //localStorage.setItem("pikerdate", pikerdate);
 function clickTracker(e) {
   setTracker(!show);
 }






useEffect(() => {
   const config = {
     headers: {
       Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
     },
   };
   //remove this date after setting up the admin pannel

   axios
     .get(
       "https:url=" +
         date,
       config

       // config
     )
     .then((res) => {
       console.log(res.data.Diet);

       let obj = res.data.Diet.find((o) => o.mealName === "lunch");
       let breakfast = res.data.Diet.find((o) => o.mealName === "breakfast");
       let earlymorning1 = res.data.Diet.find(
         (o) => o.mealName === "early morning"
       );
       let dinner = res.data.Diet.find((o) => o.mealName === "dinner");
       let afternoonsnack = res.data.Diet.find(
         (o) => o.mealName === "afternoon snack"
       );
       let middaysnack = res.data.Diet.find(
         (o) => o.mealName === "mid day snack"
       );
       let dinnerdrink = res.data.Diet.find(
         (o) => o.mealName === "dinner drink"
       );

       setearlymoring(earlymorning1);
       setDinner(dinner);
       setafternoon(afternoonsnack);
       setmidday(middaysnack);
       setdinnerdrink(dinnerdrink);
       setbreakfast(breakfast);
       setlunch(obj);
     });
 }, [date]);

console.log(date, "date logged in parent")

 return (
   <>
     {show ? <TrackerByDate dataFromParent={date} /> : null}
     <div style={{ width: "260px" }} className="res-calendar">
       <Calendar
         className={["c1", "c2"]}
         onChange={changeDate}
         onClickDay={clickTracker}
         value={dateState}
       />
     </div>
   </>
  )
}
```